# how can I know using Google AdWords API if an AdGroup is attached to a remarketting (audience)?

Tags: google-ads-api

Can someone please help me with that problem.

The question:
Using the API, How can I know if an AdGroup using remarketting or not ?

The reason:
I want to change the destination URL for the entire campaign with the API.
usually for normal ads which uses Keyword, I just update the keyword (using the Ad URL for keyword which don't have URL).
when having audience, since the Ads aren't triggered with a Keyword, I must change the Ads URL.
since changing A Ad URL require to delete and recreate an Ad I'm trying to avoid it when possible.

The real question:
When will Google for COL will allow us to update the Ad URLs.
And they can update the quality index if that's the problem for all I care.

Thanks for taking the time to read it,
R.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an FYI, the official AdWords API forum is available here:

http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/community/

An ad group that is using remarketing will contain a BiddableAdGroupCriterion containing a CriterionUserList. There are no plans to allow for ad URLs to be modifiable.